# Ansible Vault Passwords Exposed in Plain Text During Execution

Tags: ansible, password-hash, ansible-vault

I am actually using Ansible to create user, with passwords stored in an Ansible Vault.

However, I've encountered an issue where the passwords, despite being in the Ansible Vault, are displayed in plain text in the console output during playbook execution.

The relevant section of my playbook looks like this:

```yaml
- name: Create users
  become: true
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    password: "{{ item.password | password_hash('sha512', 'salt') }}"
    update_password: on_create
    state: present
    append: yes
    shell: "{{ item.shell }}"
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

When I run the playbook, it exposes passwords in plain text like this:

```
ok: [homeserver] => (item={'name': 'user1', 'groups': ['sambashare'], 'password': 'password', 'shell': '/sbin/nologin'})
ok: [homeserver] => (item={'name': 'user2', 'groups': ['sambashare'], 'password': 'azerty123', 'shell': '/sbin/nologin'})
```

I've tried the `no_log: True` option, but it completely suppresses logging for the task, which isn't what I want. I've also tried nested variable references like `"{{ '{{vaulted_password}}' | password_hash('sha512') }}"`, but they don't seem to work.

I want to keep logging enabled for debugging purposes, but I need to prevent the plain text passwords from appearing in the output. Ideally, I would like the output to show hashed versions of the passwords instead of the plain text.

Is there a way to keep my logs clean of sensitive data while still keeping the logging for other non-sensitive information?

I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

**EDIT : It seems to be a limitation of ansible's user module that prevents me from managing my user list.
I haven't found a real solution, but Zeitounator's answer may be a workaround.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the output of the loop item. As a quick fix:

```yaml
- name: Create users
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    password: "{{ item.password | password_hash('sha512', 'salt') }}"
    update_password: on_create
    state: present
    append: yes
    shell: "{{ item.shell }}"
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item | combine({password: 'redacted'}) }}"
```

You can set `label` to whatever best suit your need. See [limiting loop output with `label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label)

Please note that the above is not bullet proof and that the original password might still be available while running your playbook in verbose mode (depending on the module... I believe that `user` makes a rather good job on this one but you have to check...) and/or if you register the result of the looped task and output the result (where the orginal `item` will be available for each result element).

Comment: Thanks, it pretty much works but I'd prefer a solution where the password is just printed hashed with or without verbosity (when verbose option is added, the password is printed).

Comment: There's no way I know of to limit the output of the current `item` when running a looped task in verbose mode except using `no_log: true`, hence why my cautious warning.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I deduced, the bulletin users module doesn't seem to like the users list.
I will create them one by one. Thank you for your reply (Merci !) :)

Answer (score 1):

> *... I'd prefer a solution where the password is just printed hashed with or without verbosity ...*

The [already here given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76514779/6771046), which I recommend to accept is providing the base for that. One need just to adopt it. One approach could be in example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    users:
      - name: Alice
        password: alice
      - name: Bob
        password: bob

  tasks:

  - name: Show password
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.password | password_hash('sha512', 12345 | random(seed=item.name) | string )  }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "Hashed Password: {{ item.password | password_hash('sha512', 12345 | random(seed=item.name) | string ) }}"
    loop: "{{ users }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show password] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Hashed Password: $6$9509$KxHmwtdpZr7T3VVFbMY3aKNqzTH1wueUj2t90mDPa3jKmbBhD.VLN130tHZITbPjJzzbPjlvTZ7KDRWPd4X3c.) =>
  msg: $6$9509$KxHmwtdpZr7T3VVFbMY3aKNqzTH1wueUj2t90mDPa3jKmbBhD.VLN130tHZITbPjJzzbPjlvTZ7KDRWPd4X3c.
ok: [localhost] => (item=Hashed Password: $6$5478$dN.k/AGg.30g/aNdGhmQXeMuAdLvXVwBpI5gfohobVr7PdxMDkxeeXUk8GtQgl4PJHNGa33RQYVbHEvOn.ya61) =>
  msg: $6$5478$dN.k/AGg.30g/aNdGhmQXeMuAdLvXVwBpI5gfohobVr7PdxMDkxeeXUk8GtQgl4PJHNGa33RQYVbHEvOn.ya61
```

**Credits To**

- [Generate reusable non-random but strong password with Ansible from a seed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69583557/6771046)