# Creating a user with the same password on all servers

Tags: ansible

I wrote this playbook to create a user with the same password on all my servers, but a separate password is created for the number of servers I have.
I would be grateful if you could help me

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    user_password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=20') }}"
    user_hash_password: "{{ user_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    user_name: jack
    description: linux


  tasks:
    - name: Create deploy user
      user:
        name: "{{ user_name }}"
        password: "{{ user_hash_password }}"
        comment: "{{ description }}"
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: Send message with hashed password
      debug:
        msg: username:{{user_name}}  password:{{user_password}}
      ignore_errors: true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate reusable non-random but strong password with Ansible from a seed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69583557/6771046).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the `password` lookup is executed every time it is called, hence creating a different password for each server.

A possible workaround is to generate that password only once in a `set_fact` task which will freeze the value.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    user_name: jack
    description: linux
    user_hash_password: "{{ user_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Generate the password for all machines at once
      set_fact:
        user_password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=20') }}"
      run_once: true

    - name: Create deploy user
      user:
        name: "{{ user_name }}"
        password: "{{ user_hash_password }}"
        comment: "{{ description }}"
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: Send message with hashed password
      debug:
        msg: username:{{ user_name }}  password:{{ user_password }}
      ignore_errors: true
      run_once: true
```